# Paperclip style not respected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, imagemagick, paperclip

I have a Picture model, which has attached file picture, using Paperclip.

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
    [...]
    has_attached_file :photography, styles: { thumb: '115x', gallery: '560x560' }
    [...]
end
```

File corresponding to thumb style is perfect but file corresponding to gallery style is always 560px width. I want to obtain a file with every sides of 560px maximum.

Eg:
Original size 1000x800px => gallery size 560x468
Original size 800x1000px => gallery size 700x560

Paperclip debug output:

```
Started POST "/admin/pictures/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-29 13:21:26 +0100
Processing by Admin::PicturesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3mDW4HeWq3SV/KJ8ez09c+/Y1dNcCkqN+8uUUx5SnGk=", "picture"=>{"realization_id"=>"3",     "photography"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe984776c10 @original_filename="IFFTS-37-2.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg",     @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture[photography]\"; filename=\"IFFTS-37-2.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",     @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/gh/q_r38fpj4qv5t8ymtq713d_w0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130129-12408-a9zr3v>>, "name"=>"test", "active"=>"1"},     "_save"=>"Save"}
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/var/folders/gh/q_r38fpj4qv5t8ymtq713d_w0000gn/T/IFFTS-37-220130129-12408-ssh5ja.jpeg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/gh/q_r38fpj4qv5t8ymtq713d_w0000gn/T/IFFTS-37-220130129-12408-ssh5ja.jpeg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/gh/q_r38fpj4qv5t8ymtq713d_w0000gn/T/IFFTS-37-220130129-12408-ssh5ja.jpeg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/gh/q_r38fpj4qv5t8ymtq713d_w0000gn/T/IFFTS-37-220130129-12408-ssh5ja.jpeg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "115"     '/var/folders/gh/q_r38fpj4qv5t8ymtq713d_w0000gn/T/IFFTS-37-220130129-12408-ssh5ja20130129-12408-1boh1t1'
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/gh/q_r38fpj4qv5t8ymtq713d_w0000gn/T/IFFTS-37-220130129-12408-ssh5ja20130129-12408-1boh1t1'
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/var/folders/gh/q_r38fpj4qv5t8ymtq713d_w0000gn/T/IFFTS-37-220130129-12408-ssh5ja.jpeg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/gh/q_r38fpj4qv5t8ymtq713d_w0000gn/T/IFFTS-37-220130129-12408-ssh5ja.jpeg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/gh/q_r38fpj4qv5t8ymtq713d_w0000gn/T/IFFTS-37-220130129-12408-ssh5ja.jpeg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/gh/q_r38fpj4qv5t8ymtq713d_w0000gn/T/IFFTS-37-220130129-12408-ssh5ja.jpeg[0]' -auto-orient -resize     "560x560" '/var/folders/gh/q_r38fpj4qv5t8ymtq713d_w0000gn/T/IFFTS-37-220130129-12408-ssh5ja20130129-12408-fqtxxs'
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/gh/q_r38fpj4qv5t8ymtq713d_w0000gn/T/IFFTS-37-220130129-12408-ssh5ja20130129-12408-fqtxxs'
```

If I run the same command in terminal, everything works fine:

```
convert picture.jpeg -auto-orient -resize 560x560 picture.jpeg
```

(Same issue on Heroku)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Try Following

```
has_attached_file :photography, styles: { thumb: '115x', gallery: '560x560>' }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! with this line I also have a picture with a width of 560px...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to stop using paperclip since its heavy and use carrierwave. Its quite light. I was using paperclip initially and then switched to carrierwave. Pretty simple to deploy.

Comment: I use carrierwave for other projects but with this one I must use paperclip.